# Bluebird promise resolve is being caught as an error

Tags: node.js, bluebird

I am using promises to return data for a user do authenticate them and my resolve is showing up in my .catch for my call.

Call to the login function;

```
 function(req, username, password, done) {
        user.login(username, password).then( function(err, results){
            if (err) throw err;

            done(null, results.user);

        }).catch(
            function(err){
                console.log("Failed to log in", err);
                done(null, false);
            }
        );
}
```

Here is the promise code:

```
exports.login = function(username, password){
return new promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var sql = `CALL LOGIN(?)`;
    db.conn.query(sql, username, (err, results, fields) => {
            if (err) {
              reject("SQL ERR:", err);
            }

            var user = results[0][0];
            if (!user.uID) {
                reject("Incorrect username");
            }

            if(bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.pword)){
                resolve(user);
            } else {
                reject('Incorrect password');
            }

        });
});
}
```

When this is called, the user objet is being thrown as an error even though its being called on resolve... I am currently stuck, I tried to re-install the bluebird module as well incase something happened with it.

Comment: is `new Promise` not `new promise`

Comment: Just attempted to change it , did not work ( I am calling the module with var promise =('bluebird');

Comment: my mistake then, I've responded to your question.

Comment: A `then` callback is only called with a single argument. Having `err, results` parameters makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going on here is the next thing:

Here you are passing the user object as a param if everything is ok

```
if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.pword)) {
  resolve(user);
} else {
  reject('Incorrect password');
}
```

So in this part `.then` of your code you are receiving a user object as a unique param so there is no necessity to check if there is an error.

```
function (req, username, password, done) {
  user.login(username, password).then(function(user) {
    // a good way to see all arguments is
    // console.log(arguments);
    done(null, user);
  }).catch(
    function(err) {
      console.log("Failed to log in", err);
      done(null, false);
    }
 );
}
```